# Two or more sass includes on one line

Tags: css, sass

a Quick and simple question can't find if it is possible to do these includes on one line to avoid duplicating styles:

```
            @include breakpoint($media__tablet-to-wide) {
                width: calc(100% - 30% / 1 );
                flex-direction: row;
                height: 200px;

            }
            @include breakpoint($media__phablet-to-tablet) { 
                width: calc(100% - 30% / 1 );
                flex-direction: row;
                height: 200px;
            }
```

make these two includes into something like:

```
            @include breakpoint($media__phablet-to-tablet), @include 
            breakpoint($media__tablet-to-wide) { 
                width: calc(100% - 30% / 1 );
                flex-direction: row;
                height: 200px;
            }
```

Comment: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1065 - according to this, looks like you can. you can also just try and compile the sass and see if any error was thrown or the rendered css doesn't make sense

Comment: thanks, Pete for pointing out duplicate it solved the issue cheers